# Android: Adding a custom view to an XML

Tags: java, android, xml, canvas, view

I am currently working on a project in which I will be displaying a shape to the screen when user touches the screen.
I have created a separate class which will draw a rectangle onto a canvas, but my difficult lies in where I can specify this class in the main activities xml file in order for this to be shown alongside the buttons I have on my main activity.

I know that if I create an instance of the rectangle class and use setContentView() to this instance, it will show the rectangle just as I want it. However, I want to be able to show this rectangle alongside the buttons on my main activity.

Would anyone be able to explain how this can be done? Thanks

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/chooseColour"
    android:id="@+id/btnColour"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package mypackage;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    DrawRectangle drawRectangle = new DrawRectangle(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
}
```

DrawRectangle.java

```
package mypackage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;


public class DrawRectangle extends View {

Paint paint = new Paint();

public DrawRectangle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(30,30,100,100, paint);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You include your custom view in XML as a normal view but you change the declaration tag to your Class name. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/chooseColour"
    android:id="@+id/btnColour"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<mypackage.DrawRectangle
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnColour" />

</RelativeLayout>
```